# Context map : question about Partnership pattern

Tags: domain-driven-design

For context maps, a pattern has been added later (it was not in the original Eric Evans book) : partnership.
When I read the description in the DDD reference (pattern summary), I find only organization stuff like planning synchronisation.
But what about the model ?
I imagine the following possibilities :
- Option 1 : A sort of bidirectional Customer-Supplier. That is Bounded Context A conforms to B model for some messages and B conforms to A model for other messages.
- Option 2 : A translation layer between A and B models, with a common ownership of it.
- Option 3 : A and B both have a translation layer.
- Option 4 : A and B define a common interchange language for their exchanges : each one mapping his own model to this language.
Which options are correct ? Any other one ?

Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking (select one option of integration) is what both teams have to agree with each other. It could be whatever (one of the options you expose or maybe another).

But that's the point of this pattern: both teams are equally important, there's no Upstream and Downstream sides. One team shouldn't change its model interfaces without the other team knowing it.

The teams have to manage the integration between the two models cooperatively, that's why doesn't exist a concrete way defined in the pattern, both teams must agree on the way they integrate.

This pattern occurs when both bounded contexts are equally important, in the sense that the whole bussiness won't succeed if the other doesn't. They depends upon each other for success or fail, and they must talk to each other before changing each one's model.

Comment: I'm agree with you except for this part: "there's no Upstream and Downstream sides" ... In a Partnership relationship, both Bounded Contexts collaborate and share information bidirectionally. However, it is possible for one of the Bounded Contexts to have a more important role in the relationship, providing critical information or acting as the primary source of data. In this case, this Bounded Context can be considered the upstream and the other is the downstream.